# Defragmenting not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When I try to defragment my hard drive, it attempts a lot of passes, and then it gives up. I start it, I leave the computer alone while it runs, I come back to it, still, saying "Needs optimization (27% fragmented)." I suspect it only got that bad because the weekly scheduled defragmentations haven't been finishing either. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a third party tool, since the built-in Windows defragmentator isn't really that good.

I recommend Piriform's [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler)

This will tell you exactly which files are fragmented and how fragmented they are.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically because of

1. very large and unmovable system files (HIBERFIL.SYS, large count of restore points, and such)
2. not enough free space on the disk left
3. all of the above

Make sure you have about 20% space left, and then

- disable hibernation and swapping (temporarily),
- delete all but the last restore points
- reboot, and then
- run defragmentation again. It should work fine then.
- reenable hibernation and swapping (if you want it back)

Comment: Don't forget file system errors, run a chkdsk /r